# Simulation not working - port mapping wrong?

Tags: vhdl

[VHDL code](http://www.circuitsonline.net/forum/view/87402)

First of all, sorry for the redirect, but it's easier that way.
I'm building a digital clock, but as you can see, clock_AN and clock_seg_out do not change. Is this caused by a wrong port mapping?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your input master clock is too slow. Looking at the frequency divider cct, it looks like you've it programmed to divide a 100MHz clock. So either:

- speed up your testbench master clock
- or set the divider target to a lower number for debug purposes

Go with #2 if you want reasonable sim times!

Comment: To what speed?
Because I tried lowering it, but it didn't change a bit.

Comment: Well, if you look at the code as you have it now, nothing will happen on your seconds clock until the counter in your frequency divider has hit 100 million! 
Try lowering the counter target number to something low like 2 or 3 for debug...

Comment: Marty, I changed the count range to 2, but still my AN and seg_out's would not change. My testbench is like this:


reset <= '1';
    wait for 5 ns;
    reset <= '0';
    wait for 5 ns;
    
    set_time <= '1';
    wait for 1 ns;
    
    set_time <= '0'; -- 40 seconden
    enable_min <= '0';
    enable_hour <= '0';
    wait for 1000 ns;
        
    enable_min <= '1'; -- 11 minuten
    enable_hour <= '0';
    wait for 3700 ns;
    
    enable_min <= '0'; -- 21 uur
    enable_hour <= '1';
    wait for 200 ns;

I let the simulation run for about 10000 ns.

Comment: You wrote the code - you're in the best position to debug it!

For example, are all the counters you expect to be counting actually running? If not, trace the control & clock signals to see why not.

Clock dead? Is the divide reaching the target? 

Counters not running, but clock is alive? Any control signals not being set properly?

Comment: Marty,

You were right! Modelsim was acting strange. I've lowered the values and now it works.
Thank you!